# Is there a way to get "serial"-like output from the code running on the arduino

Tags: ros, ros-noetic

I am working on the "firmware" running on the arduino (or teensy in my case). From what I gathered so far, with the teensy 4.1 there is no reasonable way to set up a debugger with single stepping and variable viewing and so on.

So I am figuring out how to at least have debugging output generated from the firmware display somewhere convenient. With a standalone arduino I could use standard serial output, but with ROS and rosserial, this does not work.

I am looking for a way if you could give me a pointer?

Comment: Have you tried using https://github.com/ftrias/TeensyDebug? It looks like it enables GDB for Teensy. I haven't tried it myself, but it looks like it might be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have tried setting up a [`std_msgs/String`](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/String.html) publisher on the Teensy to pass basic debugging information over rosserial. It's not a true debugger, as you've noted.

Answer (score 0):

When using a Teensy with ROS, the ROS connection goes over the same serial port so that precludes using it for debugging.

To clarify: ROS runs on a Raspberry Pi (or similar), and is connected to the Teensy. I was working on firmware for the Teensy. But as it needs to talk to ROS via the serial port, I can't also use the same serial port for serial.display.